# Which processess are doing a page request on the mysites? Crawl account, My Site Cleanup Timer Job?

Tags: my-site

I have created a delegate control on mysites. This delegate control adds a webpart on the welcomepage, and after this it wil deactivate this delegate control feature. We would like that a normal user access the mysite to trigger the delegate control, and not someone else! I already exclude the crawl account because the crawl account is crawling also mysites. This crawl will do a page request and my delegate control is fired. I do not want this.

Are there also other processess like a search crawler which are doing a page request on mysites? Maybe it is the My Site Cleanup Timer Job ?

Comment: Timer jobs would not do web requests to the page, they use the object model to read data about the sites / webs /pages /etc

Comment: I found the process :) We are using a custom (scheduled task) powershell warmup script, which is looping into all sites.